# Automate chrome printing dialog

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, printing, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am asking about how to automate content of printing dialog of chrome in selenium

I found printOptions class for dialog settings(scale, background, size) but I need something to validate printed content of pages (all labels, tables,..)

Thanks in advance

I found printOptions class for dialog settings(scale, background, size) but I need something to validate printed content of pages (all labels, tables,..)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Actions class in Selenium to simulate the keyboard shortcut for opening the printing dialog like this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("p").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

Wait for the printing dialog to appear using an explicit wait. You can wait for a specific element to be present on the dialog or for the dialog to become visible.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@id='destination']")));
```

Once the printing dialog is visible, you can use Selenium to interact with the dialog